# Обработка события при фокусирование на элементе формы

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Имеется форма для заполнения, хотелось чтоб при каждой установке курсора на любом элементе формы, к примеру слева в другой ячейке, появлялась информация что туда писать и как) Данная "технология" присутствует здесь на ХешКоде, когда заполняешь форму для отправки вопроса!) Как это реализовать, подскажите) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем небольшую статью про события, там же и таблица : [ссылка](http://vvz.nw.ru/Lessons/JavaScript/events.htm).
код будет примерно такой :

```
<input type="text" id="login" onMouseDown="document.getElementById('loginAbout').style.display='block';" />
<div id="loginAbout" style="display:none;">Описание для поля логин...</div>
```

Пробуйте.

Comment: Для этой ситуации чаще применяются onfocus и onblur

Comment: Ага, спасибо) А как к примеру реализовать чтоб в одном и том же месте, при фокусирование на разных элементах, появлялась разная информация? Что для это надо? Фрейм использовать и грузить туда разные html или можно как то массивом задать разную инфу для разных элементов?)

Comment: Извините, я решил проблему!) Спасибо Enpire, за подсказку про onBlur) Всем еще раз спасибо)